# What is best practices for PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in my application and was wondering what are best practices to `setMaxTotal` connections and to `setDefaultMaxPerRoute`.

Should those values depend on a number of cores on the machine or how to calculate them? 
Should I predict load that I would have in future?

Comment: Good question, they don't have even those methods now.